# PyCharm Import files with same name in different folders

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm doing my python assignments using PyCharm. I have created folders like "Assignment 01", "Assignment 02" and so on. In each of the assignment folders, I have 2 python files. "Helper.py" and "Demo.py". In "Demo.py", I have to import the `Helper` file. I do that using

```
import Helper
```

But PyCharm doesn't recognize this unless I mark the directory containing the `Helper` files as `Sources Root`. So, I marked my directory "Assignment 01" as `Sources Root`. All is fine. Now, I started with "Assignment 02". In "Demo.py" of "Assignment 02", I imported `Helper`. This imports `Helper` from "Assignment 01" and not "Assignment 02". Even if I mark "Assignment 02" as `Sources Root`, PyCharm still refers to "Helper.py" from "Assignment 01". How to make PyCharm refer to "Helper.py" in the same folder?

Note: I don't want to open different Assignments as different projects. I would like to have everything as a single project.

Any other suggestions, conventions, best practices are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Marking as Sources Root should not be necessary inside the same Project. Are `Assignment 0*` really just folders or Python packages (i.e. do they have an `__init__.py` file in them)?

Comment: No. They don not have `__init__.py`. They're just folders.
`Assignment 0*` are sub-folders under some sub-folders. May be that's why it is asking me to mark it as `Sources Root`. I'm not exactly sure why it requires me to mark it. But if I don't mark it, PyCharm gives an error saying `No module named Helper found`. 
May be because I've multiple files with same name under different folders?

Comment: Then you should definitely turn them into packages by adding said file to each of them. It can be empty, it just has to exist. Then you can import as @hornhound outlined below in their answer.

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why I have to put the `__init__.py` file in each folder?

Comment: Yes, these files are part of [Python's import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). They turn a folder into a package that the importer can search for in all directories specified in `sys.path`, which contains all the internal folders like `site-packages` and all other folders you might add, e.g. using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. The issue with setting them as `Sources Root` is that this won't work once you try to run a program using these modules from outside PyCharm, like the shell for example.

Comment: Ohkay! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks! Let me try it once anyway. And, should I put `__init__.py` file only in the subfolders `Assignments 0*` or all its parent folders till the root? Also, can `Assignment 0*` have a space in it?

Comment: Normally, the project root is added to `sys.path` automatically by PyCharm, so you don't need an `__init__.py` directly in the project folder. But you need it all the way down in your packages when you create submodules. And no, spaces are not a good idea. They work from inside the package with relative imports but not from the outside. Better avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the root project folder as the `Sources Root`.

After that, to import Helper from Assignment01, simply do `import Assignment01.Helper`, and `import Assignment02.Helper` for Assignment02.